# Pause, resume and stop downloading with Dio package

Tags: flutter

Is there any way to pause, resume and download using dio Package?
I know that flutter_downloader package does it but I need dio for its progress approach

Answer (score -1):

```
CancelToken cancelToken = CancelToken;

downloadUrl()
{

dio.download(
    cancelToken: cancelToken
);

//Now from anywhere just,

cancelToken.cancel()

}
```

[look here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63265692/pause-resume-and-stop-downloading-with-dio-package)

Comment: your solution doesn't answer the question.

Comment: Oh sorry if it doesnt... but thats how I did mine worked quite well for me. U can look at the Dio package Documentation.

Comment: I was able to cancel the download but how to resume it from same progress where it is paused/canceled? I have checked documentation but couldn't find anything regarding pause/resume. If you can share any link or update your answer and share some code it will be really helpful.

Comment: This work just a typo: `CancelToken cancelToken = CancelToken();`
for more info: https://github.com/flutterchina/dio/blob/master/example/cancel_request.dart